# can't make my usb drive bootable

Tags: boot, usb

i'm trying to burn an iso file into my usb drive.

i've done this a number of times using 'dd'

```
# dd if=file.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=4M
```

i never had a problem with this; however this time when i apply the line it tells everything is fine but when i try to boot from the usb i got this message

```
no bootable device insert boot disk and press any key usb drive
```

i format my usb and delete the partitions and create others but it's no use

Comment: What OS are you using to burn it?

Comment: I'm using xubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the program Startup Disk Creator? It does USB as well, as long as you have the iso. I believe it is preinstalled with Ubuntu anyway. If not, go to the Software Center.

Comment: It only does USB.

Comment: it did NOT work

Comment: I also doubt you can get it on Xubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

I advise Unetbootin to make an executable USB.

For a DVD, follow these steps:

1. Insert blank DVD
2. Right click on ISO, and click `Write to disc`.
3. Make sure it has burnt it, and not just copied it - there should be lots of folders, not just an iso file.

Answer (score 0):

install unetbootin

`sudo apt-get install unetbootin`

and i am pretty sure it does well as far as making bootable USB drive

Comment: If you believe that using this tool is an answer to the problem of the OP, please give more instruction on how to use it for the purpose described by the OP in his question.